# Find circle radius having only chords lengths

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles, spheres

is it possible to find the radius of a circle, only having the lengths of two parallel chords?

Context:
The problems actually comes from a 3D one, "find the radius of a sphere having the diameter of two (parallel) inscribed discs".
It should be possible since there is only one circle/sphere with 2 parallel chords/discs inside right?

[image: Sketch]

Thank you in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to know the distance between the $2$ chords since you can have an infinite number of parallel chords within a circle.

If you do know the distance, you can follow [this](https://qr.ae/pvKLd5) link to see how you can compute the radius.